# Отметить активный слайдер кнопкой (на подобие radiobutton)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть слайдер на js, переключается автоматический и при наведении на него появляются кнопки , соответствующие одному из слайдов , нужно сделать так , что бы если активен 3 слайд то 3 кнопка выделялась как нибудь , например закрашивалась черным а другие оставались белым. Еще вопрос, как сделать анимацию появления кнопок? Пытался прописывать в hover события opacity, но получается резкое появление в любом случае

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('#change'),
  three = document.querySelectorAll('.three')[0];
var count = 0;
var runSlide = startSlide(6000);
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    three.className = 'three';
    three.classList.add('three-' + i);
    count = i;
    setInterval(function() {}, 6000)
  });
}

function startSlide(time) {
  return setInterval(function() {
    if (count == btn.length) {
      count = 0;
    }
    three.className = 'three';
    three.classList.add('three-' + count);
    count++;
  }, 6000);

}
```

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 464px;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one:hover .two {
  display: block;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

.three:hover .two {
  display: block;
}

.two {
  opacity: 0.8;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
}

.two p {
  display: inline;
}

.two div {
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0px 10px 3px 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#change {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.three {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 464px;
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.three-0 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.three-1 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(-1200px);
}

.three-2 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(-2400px);
}

.three-3 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(-3600px);
}

.three-4 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(-4800px);
}

.four {
  min-width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="three three-0">
    <div class="four" style="background: #cd1; text-align: center;">11</div>
    <div class="four" style="background: #1cd; text-align: center;">22</div>
    <div class="four" style="background: #11d; text-align: center;">33</div>
    <div class="four" style="background: #d0e; text-align: center;">44</div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div id="change">1</div>
    <div id="change">2</div>
    <div id="change">3</div>
    <div id="change">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transition на display none не срабатывает, 
а id может быть только в единственном экземрляре...

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.change'),
  three = document.querySelectorAll('.three')[0];
var count = 0;
var runSlide = startSlide(6000);
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    three.className = 'three';
    three.classList.add('three-' + i);
    for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
      btn[i].classList.remove('changeActive');

    }
    this.classList.add('changeActive');
    count = i;
    setInterval(function() {}, 6000)
  });
}

function startSlide(time) {
  return setInterval(function() {
    if (count == btn.length) {
      count = 0;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
      btn[i].classList.remove('changeActive');

    }
    btn[count].classList.add('changeActive');
    three.className = 'three';
    three.classList.add('three-' + count);
    count++;
  }, 6000);

}
```

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 464px;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.two {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.one:hover .two {
  opacity: 0.8;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.two p {
  display: inline;
}

.three {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 464px;
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.three-0 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.three-1 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(-1200px);
}

.three-2 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(-2400px);
}

.three-3 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(-3600px);
}

.three-4 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(-4800px);
}

.four {
  min-width: 1200px;
}

.change {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0px 10px 3px 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.changeActive {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  transition: all .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="three three-0">
    <div class="four" style="background: #cd1; text-align: center;">11</div>
    <div class="four" style="background: #1cd; text-align: center;">22</div>
    <div class="four" style="background: #11d; text-align: center;">33</div>
    <div class="four" style="background: #d0e; text-align: center;">44</div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="change">1</div>
    <div class="change">2</div>
    <div class="change">3</div>
    <div class="change">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , а как сделать radiobutton,  что бы выделялась кнопка которая относиться к определенному слайду?

Comment: уже сделал...  я свой пример и не сразу узнал)))

Comment: кстати, а что заradiobutton?

Comment: ну радиобатон это когда болучается один элемент отличается от других , вот у меня 4 кнопки есть , и соответственно 4 слада к ним , и я хотел что бы при переключении слайдов менялась еще активная кнопка , что бы знать какой сейчас слайд по счету работает

Comment: ну я уже сделал, ты не смотрел пример?

Comment: И еще обрати внимание на свои элементы  id="change". Я их изменил на class. Запомни, на всей странице ID должен быть уникальным и единственным  и у элемента может быть только один ID

Comment: да я посмотрел , то что я хотел , спасибо , уже не первый раз помогаете , про class и id учту )

Comment: всегда пожалуйста...